How to keep the main camera perspective remains consistent?
The problem is when running the game and the when the flag bool variable rotateObjectItself is either true or false in the start and then changing its state it also changing the camera rotation on the X.
When the flag is set to true and if the camera is rotating around the object on all axis it's logic to see the sky too but then when changing the flag back to false i want it to return and that the main camera rotation on the X will be return to it's default but the rotation is locked on the value -84 on the X.
using UnityEngine;

public class GlobalRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public Transform rotatingCamera;
    public float rotationSpeed = 60;
    public Vector3 cameraOffset = new Vector3(0, 5, -10); // Adjust this to get the best view
    public bool rotateAroundX = false;
    public bool rotateAroundY = true; // Default to Y-axis rotation
    public bool rotateAroundZ = false;
    public bool rotateObjectItself = false; // If true, rotate the object around itself, otherwise rotate the camera around the object

    private Transform objectToRotate;
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        if (target == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Target Cube not found");
            return;
        }

        // Determine the transforms
        objectToRotate = target.transform;
        cameraTransform = rotatingCamera ? rotatingCamera : Camera.main.transform;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Determine the rotation axis based on the selected booleans
        Vector3 rotationAxis = new Vector3(rotateAroundX ? 1 : 0, rotateAroundY ? 1 : 0, rotateAroundZ ? 1 : 0);

        if (rotateObjectItself)
        {
            // Rotate the object around its own axis
            objectToRotate.Rotate(rotationAxis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            // Optionally keep the camera looking at the object
            if (cameraTransform != null)
            {
                cameraTransform.position = objectToRotate.position + cameraOffset;
                cameraTransform.LookAt(objectToRotate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Rotate the camera around the target
            cameraTransform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, rotationAxis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            cameraTransform.LookAt(target.transform);
        }
    }
}

this screenshot is when the camera rotating around the cube. the main camera rotation on the x is 7.95

now i checked true the flag and the camera are not rotating anymore and the cube is rotating around itself.
and now the camera is also facing up to the sky like it's looking at the cube from the bottom. and i want it to keep looking at like it was in the start when the camera was rotating around the cube.


The following script allows you to rotate an object about its LOCAL axis depending on your selection in the inspector. Moreover, it is also possible to make the camera rotate about the GLOBAL y-axis of the object. Both rotations can happen simultaneously. By default the object rotates about its local y-axis on play. Don't forget to reference the target object as well as a camera on the script component in the inspector:
using UnityEngine;

public class GlobalRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objectToRotate;
    public Transform rotatingCamera;

    [Tooltip("If true, rotate the object about LOCAL axis of object")]
    public bool rotateObject;
    [Tooltip("If true, rotate referenced camera around object about GLOBAL y-axis of object")]
    public bool rotateCam;

    [Tooltip("Enable if object should rotate about local x-axis. Has no effect if rotating camera around object.")]
    public bool rotateObjAroundX = false;
    [Tooltip("Enable if object should rotate about local y-axis. Has no effect if rotating camera around object.")]
    public bool rotateObjAroundY = true;
    [Tooltip("Enable if object should rotate about local z-axis. Has no effect if rotating camera around object.")]
    public bool rotateObjAroundZ = false;

    public float rotationSpeed = 60;

    // Camera rotates around GLOCAL y-axis of object
    private Vector3 camRotAxis = Vector3.up;


    void Start()
    {
        // Rotate object about local y-axis by default
        rotateObject = true;
        rotateCam = false;

        rotateObjAroundX = false;
        rotateObjAroundY = true;
        rotateObjAroundZ = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Check if rotating object
        if (rotateObject)
        {
            // Determine LOCAL rotation axis
            Vector3 localRotAxis = new Vector3(rotateObjAroundX ? 1 : 0, rotateObjAroundY ? 1 : 0, rotateObjAroundZ ? 1 : 0);

            // Rotate the object around its own axis
            objectToRotate.Rotate(localRotAxis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Check if rotating camera
        if (rotateCam)
        {
            // Rotate the camera around the objectToRotate
            rotatingCamera.RotateAround(objectToRotate.position, camRotAxis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            rotatingCamera.LookAt(objectToRotate);
        }
    }
}

Let me know if this is what you were trying to achieve or not and we can make some adjustments if needed.

some things i want to ask.  when i start the game when only Rotate Object is true and only Rotate Obj Around Y is true when i look on the Cube in the inspector i see all 3 axis rotating.  not only the Y even if in the game window it looks like it's rotating only on one axis.  why in the inspector i see the cube rotating on all 3 axis ? second , how to make that the camera can be rotating also on all 3 axis ?  because if the Rotate Cam is check only and all the axis checked true the camera is still rotating only on the Y.  but in that case i want the camera to rotate on all axis.

If I understand you correctly you are wondering why all three of the rotation values in the transform of the cube are changing even though rotation about y-axis only is enabled? This is probably because your cube is prerotated. The rotation values in the inspector denote euler angles relative to the local initial coordinate systems axes. Therefore if your cube is sligthly rotated in the beginning, rotating about local y-axis still means other values can change.

That's on me, I assumed you don't want rotation of the camera about other axes. What behavior exactly do you want? Since rotating the camera about different axes and even at the same time results in let's say particular camera movement, I assumed you actually don't want that.
